# Inputs that clear default values on focus, display formatted numbers and store converted data into observables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

**Background**

I am attempting to create user-friendly input elements that meet the following criteria:

- Parses & validates user input.
- Displays a greyed-out hint when empty and not focused.
- Displays formatted values when not focused.
- Minimises unnecessary keystrokes and mouse-clicks by removing formatting when focused.
- Stores a numeric value internally, for use in mathematical calculations.

I have attempted to implement the above using a custom knockout binding handler, but I seem to have written myself into a corner when it comes to reusing this logic to display formatted output within span elements.

**Issue**

In the fiddle below, I define a 'number' binding. E.g. `<input data-bind="number: price">`

This binding uses event handling to achieve the above criteria, writes primitive JavaScript numbers into the observable, and writes formatted strings back into the input element's value.

Unfortunately it also leaves me a bit stumped on how to best display the output:

- Using `<span data-bind="number: price"></span>` does not work as the number handler is hard-coded into updating the element's value.
- Using `<span data-bind="text: price"></span>` means I lose the formatting rules written into the number handler.
- Using `<input readonly data-bind="number: price">` breaks the flow of text within sentences, and seems like it would result in an unintuitive user experience due to the display of an unusable input.

Any suggestions on how to cleanly and elegantly achieve the above criteria would be much appreciated.

**Examples**

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rokiyo/SAgV5/

Note: While this example focuses on numeric input, I will eventually want to do the same for text and data inputs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an observable that fronts your backing value to handle the formatting, unformatting.

IMHO the best way to do it is to create a wrapper via the subscribable fn extensibility point.

The only change to your fiddle HTML is to change the 2 text bindings

```
<span data-bind="text: waterUsed.formattedValue">
<span data-bind="text: discount.formattedValue">
```

I have also changed the number binding to use a placeholder attribute on the input instead of trying to muck around with value and css values.

The asFormattedNumber function is attached to all subscribables.  It also ensures that the underlying observable is always a number.

You could also override the text binding to check if the observable has a formattedValue and rewrite the valueAccessor before calling the real text binding, similar to how the number binding below just delegates to the value binding.

---

```
ko.subscribable.fn['asFormattedNumber'] = function (defaultValue, options) {
    var target = this;

    var prefix = options.prefix || '';
    var postfix = options.postfix || '';
    var decimals = options.decimals || 0;
    var isFixed = options.isFixed || false;
    var roundFactor = Math.pow(10, decimals);

    // Very basic - Doesn't assume any number format
    var valueExtractor = new RegExp( '^' + (prefix ? '\\' + prefix : '' ) + '([0-9\\.\\,]+)' + (postfix ? '\\' + postfix : '' ) + '$' );

    // Extracts the number portion a formatted string
    var unformatter = function( value ) {
        // If not a match, just return the value
        return (value.match(valueExtractor) || ['', value])[1];
    };

    // Formats the value according to options
    var formatter = function(value) {

        // If no value, return empty string.  Important to tell the difference
        // for when the default value is entered into the input box
        if ( value === undefined || value === null ) {
            return '';
        }
        return prefix + value.toFixed(decimals) + postfix;
    };

    // This is the observable the world will see
    var wrapperObs = ko.observable();

    // If true, formatted value will be blank and placeholder should be shown
    var wrapperIsEmpty = true;
    // Flag to stop recursion
    var wrappedIsBeingSet = false;

    // Check if the target observable is writeable.  If it isn't then our wrapper can never be set,
    // so no point in setting up a subscription on the wrapperObs.
    if ( ko.isWriteableObservable(target) ) {
        wrapperObs.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            wrappedIsBeingSet = true;
            if ( newValue === '' ) {
                wrapperIsEmpty = true;
                target(defaultValue);
                return;
            }

            var unformattedValue = unformatter(newValue);
            var parsed = parseFloat(unformattedValue);

            if ( isNaN(parsed) && target() === defaultValue ) {
                wrapperObs('');
                return;
            }

            if ( isFixed ) {
                parsed = Math.round( parsed * roundFactor ) / roundFactor;
            }

            if ( parsed !== target() ){
                target(parsed);
            }

            wrapperObs( formatter(parsed ));
        });
    }

    target.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        // Handles situations where input is empty and resets target to defaultValue;
        if ( !wrappedIsBeingSet ) {
            var formattedValue = formatter(newValue)

            wrapperObs(formattedValue);
        }

        wrapperIsBeingSet = false;
    });

    // Initialise initial state
    if ( target() === undefined ) {
        wrapperObs('');
    } else {
        target.notifySubscribers(target());
    }

    // Add stuff to the public observable.
    wrapperObs.value = target;
    wrapperObs.placeholder = formatter(defaultValue);
    wrapperObs.unformattedValue = ko.computed( function() {
        return wrapperIsEmpty && target() === defaultValue ? '' : target();
    });
    wrapperObs.formattedValue = ko.computed( function() { 
        return formatter(target());
    });

    return wrapperObs;
}
// custom knockout binding for managing formatted numeric inputs such as dollars, kilolitres & percentages
ko.bindingHandlers.number = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $el = $(element),
            obsValue = valueAccessor();

        $el.attr('placeholder', obsValue.placeholder);

        // prepare input field for editing by removing unneccessary characters (dollar signs, etc)
        $el.focus(function () {
            this.value = obsValue.unformattedValue();
            $el.attr('placeholder', '');
        });

        // restore proper input field format (showing dollars signs, etc)
        $el.blur(function () {
            this.value = obsValue();
            $el.attr('placeholder', obsValue.placeholder);
        });

        return ko.bindingHandlers['value'].init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.bindingHandlers['value'].update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.waterUsed = ko.observable().asFormattedNumber(0, {
        postfix: " KL",
        decimals: 3
    });

    self.price = ko.observable().asFormattedNumber(0, {
        prefix: "$",
        decimals: 3,
        isFixed: true
    });

    self.discount = ko.observable().asFormattedNumber(0, {
        postfix: "%",
        decimals: 0
    });

    self.grossCost = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.waterUsed.value() * self.price.value();
    }).asFormattedNumber(0, {
        prefix: "$",
        decimals: 2,
        isFixed: true
    });

    self.netCost = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.grossCost.value() - (self.grossCost.value() * (self.discount.value() / 100));
    }).asFormattedNumber(0, {
        prefix: "$",
        decimals: 2,
        isFixed: true
    });
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: I think I'll stick your wrapper solution, I'm not too keen on overriding library functions...  I forgot to mention that I need IE8 compatibility, so no placeholder for me... But a bit of googling did turn up this link, which seems to achieve a similar result: http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html